# JWT Authentification invalid Credentials with the token

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com, lexikjwtauthbundle, symfony6

I am new to Symfony and jwt Authentication.

I tried to set up an access to api platform resources with a jwt token.

I followed the doc https://symfony.com/bundles/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/current/index.html to set up the token.

My problem comes after the token generation, on PostMan I add the generated token in Authorization -> Type : Bearer Token -> Token: the token, and when I make the request I get a return:

{
"code": 401,
"message": "Invalid JWT Token"
}
Token generation:
[image]

Token info:
[image]
Request get/Users:
[image]
Security.yaml
[image]

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/issues/736

Comment: my login is not a problem jwt does generate a token for me, the problem comes after when I want to use the token to make requests.

Comment: Good to see you found the solution in the referred github issue anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem

To connect I use the email field, while LexitJWT uses the username. I don't know why it doesn't block me from generating the token.
To fix the problem just go to the config/packages/lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml file and add user_identity_field: email

[image]